# R Package Needs Other Packages That Are Not Called

Tags: r, package

I am creating an R package that calls some other R packages, that have their own dependencies.

Specifically, some of the packages need edgeR and RPMM to work, but neither is automatically installed when the packages that use them are. I can just add both to my package's Imports fields in the DESCRIPTION file, but then running `devtools::check()` throws a warning that neither are imported from.

What is the correct method to ensure that these packages are installed when installing my package?

Comment: You would also need to import the package or a function from it in the `NAMESPACE` file, eg `import(edge)` and `import(RPMM)`

Comment: Hadley Wickham's [R packages](https://r-pkgs.org/) should tell you all you need to know.  Since you're already using `devtools`, `usethis::use_package("<package name>")` would be the obvious tool for package management.

Comment: "devtools::check() throws a warning that neither are imported from": what does this mean?  Are you namespacing all references to functions from other packages in your code?  For example, `stats::quantile()` rather than just `quantile()`?

Comment: @Limey, when running `devtools::check()` I get the following NOTE:
Namespace in Imports filed not imported from:
'RPMM' 'edgeR'
All declared Imports should be used.

I am namespacing all references to functions, yes. However, I am not calling any functions from those two packages. Other functions that I am calling functions from are.

Comment: The packages that are needed by a package need to be listed in _both_ `NAMESPACE` (which can be managed with `devtools`) and `DESCRIPTION` (which is never managed/rewritten by `devtools`). In addition to making sure they are imported in NAMESPACE, you need to add them to the `Imports:` or `Suggests:` sections of the second file.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you, that solved the issue.